# How to use volatile flag to continue running run method only for the last Thread instance

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've used variable `exit` as a volatile boolean flag to pause execution of the run method in my Runnable. `exit` variable is defined in my Activity class:

```
private volatile boolean exit = false;
```

On button click event I perform instantiation of new Thread with following Runnable:

```
class CounterRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Menu menu;

    public CounterRunnable(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 10;
        while(!exit) {
            if (i > 0) {

                final int finalI = i;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        MenuItem counterMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_counter);
                        counterMenuItem.setTitle(Integer.toString(finalI));
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            i--;
            Log.d("Thread name: ", Thread.currentThread().getName() + " i: " + i);
            if (i == 0) { break; }
        }

        scanning = false;
        bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(LeScanCallback);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();

    }

    private void stop() {
        exit = true;
    }

    public void start() {
        exit = false;
    }
}
```

An instance of such runnable is passed to a new thread instance when a user clicks button for scanning. The app is used to scan Bluetooth devices.
When the scan button is clicked, it started a countdown from 10 to 0.
The user has the option to stop scanning by pressing another stop button and every time they press stop and then start again, I instantiate new thread instance with runnable defined above.
So here is my code which instantiates new thread:

```
counterRunnable = new CounterRunnable(menu);
if (!scanning) {
    counterRunnable.stop();
} else {
    counterThread = new Thread(counterRunnable);
    counterThread.start();
    counterRunnable.start();
}
```

The `scanning` variable is set to true if the user has clicked scan and false if the user has clicked stop.
When the user, for some reason, clicks stop and scan button more than one time and too fast, it will generate a lot of threads.

How to allow only the last instance of thread to access run method and terminate all previous thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about join the current `counterThread` before starting the next new thread.

When user clicked stop button, we can stop and join the current `counterThread` to block click event handling (main thread) until current `counterThread` stops (only for few milliseconds).

Then we can handle the incoming start button click, and start a new thread after we completely stopped the previous one.

Here is an example.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = "multithreadmenuupdate";

    private Button mStartButton;
    private Button mStopButton;
    private Menu mMainMenu;
    private CounterThread mCounterThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize member fields
        mStartButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        mStopButton = findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        mMainMenu = null;
        mCounterThread = null;

        // Set click listeners for buttons
        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mStopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        mMainMenu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, mMainMenu);
        // must return true for the menu to be displayed
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {

            // Start button clicked?
            case R.id.startButton:
                // Thread is already running?
                if(null != mCounterThread && !mCounterThread.isStopped().get()) break;

                mCounterThread = new CounterThread(mMainMenu);
                mCounterThread.start();
                break;

            // Stop button clicked?
            case R.id.stopButton:
                // No thread?
                if(null == mCounterThread) break;

                // Interrupt thread to stop
                mCounterThread.interrupt();
                try {
                    // Wait until current thread stops
                    mCounterThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    class CounterThread extends Thread {

        private static final int COUNT_DOWN_START = 10;
        private Menu mMenu;
        // Indicates if thread is being stopped
        // Initially true because the thread is in stopped state
        private final AtomicBoolean mIsStopped = new AtomicBoolean(true);

        public CounterThread(Menu menu) {
            mMenu = menu;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int countDownValue = COUNT_DOWN_START;

            // Is not stopped?
            while(!mIsStopped.get()) {

                // Count down finished?
                if(countDownValue == 0) break; // stop thread

                // Update menu item with count down value
                updateMenuItem(countDownValue);

                logThreadMenuUpdate(countDownValue);

                // Wait for 1 sec
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // 1000ms = 1s
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    // Thread has been interrupted to stop?
                    if(mIsStopped.get()) break; // stop thread
                }

                // Count down
                countDownValue--;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void start() {
            // Change to false allowing thread to run
            mIsStopped.set(false);
            super.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            // Thread is being interrupted to stop
            // Change to true for thread to stop
            mIsStopped.set(true);
            super.interrupt();
        }

        public AtomicBoolean isStopped() {
            return mIsStopped;
        }

        private void updateMenuItem(final int countDownValue) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_counter).setTitle(Integer.toString(countDownValue));
                }
            });
        }

        private void logThreadMenuUpdate(int countDownValue) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.append("Thread name: ").append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            str.append(" - ").append(countDownValue);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, str.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

In above example, I replaced your `CounterRunnable` class with `CounterThread`.

Your can find the `MainActivity` implementation also.

As I have added the Activity implementation, I'll add the activity layout and menu resource XMLs as well.

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```xml
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/stopButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/startButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

res/menu/main.xml

```xml
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_counter"
        android:title="Counter"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Here's a screenshot of my example activity.
[image]

I tested this using a physical device, by rapidly tapping & switching between start and stop buttons. Seems like it works well.

Comment: Yes, join is exactly what I needed to solve my problem. It stops thread instance from executing before creating and executing a new one and we have always one thread instance which is updating UI. I only added counterThread.join() after counterRunnable.stop() and it solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Lakidu offers one different solution which is maybe better than mine, but if you want to use CounterRunnable class which implements Runnable class instead of extending Thread class, joining threads solves the problem.

```
counterRunnable = new CounterRunnable(menu);
if (!scanning) {
    counterRunnable.stop();
    try {
        counterThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} else {
    counterThread = new Thread(counterRunnable);
    counterThread.start();
    counterRunnable.start();
}
```